# Vaadin Table with IndexedContainer column size issue

Tags: width, vaadin

I extended IndexedContainer to be used with a paginated Table. The Table is set with undefined size (so does the upline hierarchy) so when it is first rendered, i.e. page 1, all columns have their width computed dynamically, which is fine.

When switching to another page the custom IndexedContainer reloads a new set of items and these are successfully picked up and rendered by the Table. However, the Table does not adjust the column widths according to the new set of items. Basically, the column widths are exactly the ones computed dynamically for page 1..

I've been trying to fix this by manually:

- setColumnWidth(..., -1) on all columns
- setSizeUndefined(), again, on the Table
- setWidth(-1, ...) on the Table
- marksAsDirty(Recursive)() on both the Table and UI

but nothing worked as expected.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

(Also posted at https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4015043)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested at https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/4015043 there is an experimental *alwaysRecalculateColumnWidths* boolean flag within Table to overcome this issue (column resize on item set change). The flag is protected, initialized to false and doesn't have a setter yet so one needs to extend Table to set it true.